# You have reached a limit for sending mail. Your message was not sent Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

We are using Gmail API to send email. As per Gmail documentation we can send upto 500 emails per day but when we send more than 60 email we are getting this error on our Gmail account.

> You have reached a limit for sending mail. Your message was not sent.

As per our code logic we are sending text email and one email in every two min to avoid Google API 100 second Quota. We have also checked the API console and in the last few days we have not reached our Quotas limit and not Received any errors but we are getting the above mention Error in our Gmail account. One last thing we want to mention is that we are only using Gmail send service. Thanks in advance.

Edit 1 :

We are only using one email address per email and this is our message original.

```
> Delivered-To: xyz@gmail.com
Received: by 10.36.69.2 with SMTP id y2csp7268660ita;
        Mon, 23 Oct 2017 05:57:25 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.157.40.142 with SMTP id s14mr7651348ota.123.1508763444992;
        Mon, 23 Oct 2017 05:57:24 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1508763444; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=00GKWt5YJyup/zRaygHJ3YjdXhfUTp24XlsHFbRPJtoN4umiasNg/fhQ59VSR8cu4Q
         Z2CLHOVxD9FoNb0UW3+4SJAHyrAaf2ZUnvbh9kUMNenVSNk1zYX2DaumMnaiUI+75eCj
         oNzFEV4i5Ja/WQbr8kYziynh6d3oFgX81JqAC9ptphoZ2L3TJt0rxli/77+eNF2c7HSs
         YTXDdsd2i8Hmm+aWaYQ/h5u8YABWmkiOFX/6xqAbxcBH65Ye1uLFR1+uWPPfcmzd13GC
         KOyRbcbq5WAMBXI14Xuit+llwE9IgSb6dtiFxJ8oYNHZa4GBsv2HzaTiRrZeoc41rNEK
         qWHA==ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=to:subject:message-id:date:mime-version:from:dkim-signature
         :arc-authentication-results;
        bh=TRygSnH7m96UEJAVfmK31uQcIqHJNyzan4DHUUOb9L0=;
        b=HANggRPcRICCeKYpqmsbnYKcsMi8esLWFTf5tPLV8dXcXeLudPJtxPr2nOT5KK8ezt
         Orgm6voF+si5jYJInKwLDmCpFrY9jogQQP39yknN9H0SqPH+awtn0HT4dvoeq9Wnr3Sq
         dGPfQbqtYyT7T8ISDuT5rsjB2zI61Md8eWOCRO/dbfv+lovyYbfUbwoVG73LhSv4hGeX
         2Nk0Lki/4DesnLk98wdUbwchY6Y78Trns1+tfi7awSClXlaobje2K4hz7i1y96R+9kpn
         0yYGfTLtlCc65QfsKXJnSF42kZ32HlttuBQRjb5W6ua8gEBCCffxydD/v4cQ3e8iVSaT
         UPWw==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@gmail.com header.s=20161025 header.b=GLxhRGM2;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of xyz@gmail.com designates 209.85.220.65 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=xyz@gmail.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=gmail.com
Return-Path: <xyz@gmail.com>
Received: from mail-sor-f65.google.com (mail-sor-f65.google.com. [209.85.220.65])
        by mx.google.com with SMTPS id j196sor1073671oib.38.2017.10.23.05.57.24
        for <xyz@gmail.com>
        (Google Transport Security);
        Mon, 23 Oct 2017 05:57:24 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of xyz@gmail.com designates 209.85.220.65 as permitted sender) client-ip=209.85.220.65;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@gmail.com header.s=20161025 header.b=GLxhRGM2;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of xyz@gmail.com designates 209.85.220.65 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=xyz@gmail.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=gmail.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20161025;
        h=from:mime-version:date:message-id:subject:to;
        bh=TRygSnH7m96UEJAVfmK31uQcIqHJNyzan4DHUUOb9L0=;
        b=GLxhRGM2PoE2cV4Kv157dJ1SiFzqBCvjV9ksWGdO+3fm+NluMUY5qZ2XeDWsfxEqCV
         AarV0FEoPqFEUkeDUpiwwz6FYRlPcqYGX91CQLyitB4QE4FHSzseiPFI8S21xXdqUn8X
         wLnNW9k1fPs1y07d8OMP6CKmu5Cf3t2vbCieNj2/Btg4Ga3rDTpKo+LPdbyM0Oddr7ZZ
         28W/iX/w3Q23fXZHhnpV5KKUab84df3fjSq5Vh/7WccUeAHIfudJQyn71xwjbpXGRxP+
         iIILNOY6OR3lymHWXUki7FADK5/CREGfuKQJO0axZ/EUHYH942TAW/q74G3lGHNb5Dmq
         4eqQ==
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20161025;
        h=x-gm-message-state:from:mime-version:date:message-id:subject:to;
        bh=TRygSnH7m96UEJAVfmK31uQcIqHJNyzan4DHUUOb9L0=;
        b=ThGC7Ye92WeBnpv88tssmK3jxoTh75t0TE0YSwIe7neSPQ9nkd02LfUy2E2I5DYYJl
         Yu03UIUCnEyCECDx2N1chki4ifgXBMIXT2MNaN/V3dveaLEc3C8jyF3loTvTSFC63Sv/
         fxsQgBQNmtH/RqkxG+c1rFGjclTdvmTaERHB2IiAuVzuEyAXaeFS6pippckq8W4CkfMb
         VLawraTAdqKvgfCUEe7O6AdPhsaCSkWNgrBhigIXaVOSEnVAnywNeGxOzxZ6iK/vdUAT
         bTJQTap/OL80gGk8or8MMuKDg1wNhv2PWyCUG/OASdY0FELNmj9gkcyeGJMmNBtLVfUy
         3fPA==
X-Gm-Message-State: AMCzsaUOyy2JRzefxuZ+o3ROgrkTqFWfyu7Ox69vaaKaM19XX0T+88Th qGn9LmtYLTmLeVaaakvk3IeYDENzVWdRJwFw0BM=
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ABhQp+TqkpdDhP6uWvv5qUap3QIYchZYDradVOJSJlPXHTlHNnZBUXUQ7vdOdo5XThqLprbv/VlFJANYzjGyQg+QpAo=
X-Received: by 10.202.90.3 with SMTP id o3mr6602265oib.27.1508763444353; Mon, 23 Oct 2017 05:57:24 -0700 (PDT)
Received: from 385619130527 named unknown by gmailapi.google.com with HTTPREST; Mon, 23 Oct 2017 05:57:23 -0700
From: XYZ <XYZ@gmail.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Mon, 23 Oct 2017 05:57:23 -0700
Message-ID: <CALB+=oPhh7AmZJSyimZXZb38SwNAD7eMFioUFv6GmZzdcWrU9A@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Important Game
To: xyz@gmail.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="001a113d5edc26a056055c365d7e"
--001a113d5edc26a056055c365d7e
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
```

Comment: How many recipients do you send the messages too? According to [Gmail Sending limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en), even if you send email but the recipients are 10, that still counts as 50 quotas, not 5 (quota/mail). You can also check that doc for more info on what counts towards a user's limits.

Comment: We are sending one recipient per email.